# Wait for For loop to finish - Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop

I have this code that formats the parameters and submits to api.

```
                for (let a = 0; a < perfCriteria.length; a++) {
                    const element = perfCriteria[a];
                    let newObject = Object.assign({}, paramObject)
                    newObject.performanceCriteria = element.performanceCriteriaId
                    for (let b = 0; b < element.performanceIndicators.length; b++) {
                        const element2 = element.performanceIndicators[b];
                        let newObject2 = Object.assign({}, newObject)
                        newObject2.performanceIndicator = element2.performanceIndicatorId
                        newObject2.numberTarget = element2.divisionTarget ? element2.divisionTarget : ""
                        newObject2.targetDetails = element2.targetDetails
                        for (let c = 0; c < element2.targetDetails.length; c++) {
                            const element = element2.targetDetails[c];
                            element2.targetDetails[c].individualAccountable = element.individualAccountable.map(function(row){
                                return row._id
                            })
                        }

                        divTargetArray.push(newObject2)
                    }
                }

                this.DivisionTarget.create(divTargetArray).subscribe(result =>{
                    console.log('result', result)
                    if(result.success){
                        this.appComponent.showLoadingIndicator = false;
                        this.router.navigate(['/index/app/performanceManagement/divisionTargets']);
                        this.toastService.openSnackBar(result.message, "success");
                    }else{
                        this.appComponent.showLoadingIndicator = false;
                        this.toastService.openSnackBar(result.message, "danger");
                    }
                }, error => {
                    this.appComponent.showLoadingIndicator = false;
                    this.toastService.openSnackBar(error, "danger");
                });
```

But sometimes, it will not wait for the For loop to finish. Is there a way that I can wait for the For loop to finish before proceeding to submit it to API?

Comment: I agree with Dawid's comment. Is your code breaking somewhere in there?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any asynchronous operations in your code so I think it's executed line by line. It seems like there is no possibility that subscription happens before loop has ended. Maybe issue is somewhere else?